# How to insert Turkish characters correctly in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I can't insert Turkish characters in database correctly. If I change them in database manually they are correctly viewed on the page. One strange thing: I can edit the text with 'edit page' function then they are correctly inserted in the database!! To make it more clear:

create_album function(which does not insert Turkish characters correctly)

```
function create_album($album_header, $album_name, $album_place,) {
  $album_header = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($album_header));
  $album_name = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($album_name));
  $album_place = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($album_place));

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `albums` VALUES ('','".$_SESSION['user_id']."', 
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '$album_status Beklemede', '$album_header', '$album_name',
  '$album_place')");
  mkdir('uploads/'.mysql_insert_id(), 0744);
  mkdir('uploads/thumbs/'.mysql_insert_id(), 0744);
}
```

edit_album function (which edits and inserts Turkish characters correctly)

```
 function edit_album($album_id, $album_header, $album_name, $album_place) {
   $album_id = (int)$album_id;
   $album_header = mysql_real_escape_string($album_header);
   $album_name = mysql_real_escape_string($album_name);
   $album_place = mysql_real_escape_string($album_place);

   mysql_query("UPDATE `albums` SET `header`='$album_header', `name`='$album_name',
   `place`='$album_place' WHERE `album_id`=$album_id AND   
   `user_id`=".$_SESSION['user_id']);
 }
```

P.S: I have in my database charset=utf8_turkish_ci and after mysql_query() I set

```
 mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
 mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
 mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION='utf8_general_ci'");
```

What is the difference here? Why does't `create_album` function insert Turks. Char. correctly?

My php/mysql knowledge is limited so if you need to know more about the problem, I would like to share.

Comment: for one thing, you have an extra comma here `create_album($album_header, $album_name, $album_place,)` at the end. For an other the only visible difference is [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) try removing htmlentities from your first function

Comment: Man!!!! you have no idea how long I have been busy with that problem!! It is solved!! I use now htmlspecialchars and it works!:) THANK YOU!!